# How and why to use pre-versions

Tags: version-control, npm-publish

I'm working on an NPM package, and I'm using [NP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/np) to publish. When choosing what version to bump to, four of the options are pre[something].

```sh
prepatch    1.0.1 -> 1.0.2-0
preminor    1.0.1 -> 1.1.0-0
premajor    1.0.1 -> 2.0.0-0
prerelease  1.0.1 -> 1.0.2-0
```

What do these mean, and what's the difference between `prepatch` and `prerelease`?